# Jackson Scala JSON Deserialization to case classes

Tags: json, scala, jackson, deserialization

I have a JSON which has following form:

```
{
"inventory": [
           {
        "productType": "someProduct1",
        "details": {
            "productId": "Some_id",
            "description": "some description"
        }
        },
 {
        "productType": "someProduct2",
        "details": {
            "productId": "Some_id",
            "description":{"someKey":"somevalue"}
        }
    }
]
}
```

The case classes that I want the above json to deserialize look like following:

```
case class Inventory(products:List[Product])
case class Product(productType:String,details:ProductDetails)
abstract class ProductDetails
case class ProductDetailsSimple(productId:String,description:String) extends ProductDetails
case class ProductDetailsComplex(productId:String,description:Map[String,String]) extends ProductDetails
```

I am using [jackson-scala module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) to deserialize the above JSON string as follows:

```
 val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
 mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
 mapper.readValue(jsonBody, classOf[Inventory])
```

The error I get is as follows:
     "Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property '@details' that is to contain type id  (for class ProductDetails)\n at [Source: java.io.StringReader@12dfbabd; line: 9, column: 5]"

I have been through [jackson documentation on Polymorphic deserialization](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) and have tried combinations as mentioned but with no luck. 
I would like to understand what I am doing wrong here, which needs correction with respect to deserialization using jackson module.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think there's a few separate problems to address here, so I've listed three separate approaches.

## TL;DR

Either use Jackson polymorphism correctly or, in your case, go to a simpler approach and remove the need for the polymorphism. See my [code on github](https://github.com/aellerton/so-scala-jackson-polymorphic).

## 1. Custom Deserializer

Your formatted JSON is:

```
{ inventory:
   [ { productType: 'someProduct1',
       details:
        { productId: 'Some_id',
          description: 'some description' } },
     { productType: 'someProduct2',
       details:
        { productId: 'Some_id',
          description: { someKey: 'somevalue' } 
        }
     } 
   ]
}
```

The field `productType` is misplaced, in my opinion, but if this format is a strict requirement then you could write your own deserializer that looks at the `productType` field and instantiates a different concrete class.

I don't think this would be the best solution so I didn't write example code, but I like the [Joda date-time package](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/deser/DateTimeDeserializer.java) as a reference for custom serialize/deserialize

## 2. Jackson Polymorphism

You've separated `Product` from `ProductDetails` with a type field:

```
case class Product(productType:String,details:ProductDetails)

abstract class ProductDetails
```

I think you've confused how Jackson's polymorphic data type handling works and complicated your class design as a result.

Perhaps your business rules require that a product has a "type", in which case I'd name it "kind" or some other non-code label, and put it into what you've called `ProductDetails`.

But if "type" was included in an attempt to get type polymorphism working, then it isn't the right way.

I've included the below as a working example of Jackson polymorphism in Scala:

```
/**
 * The types here are close to the original question types but use 
 * Jackson annotations to mark the polymorphic JSON treatment.
 */

import scala.Array
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.{JsonSubTypes, JsonTypeInfo}

@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
  property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(Array(
  new Type(value = classOf[ProductDetailsSimple], name = "simple"),
  new Type(value = classOf[ProductDetailsComplex], name = "complex")
))
abstract class Product

case class ProductDetailsSimple(productId: String, description: String) extends Product

case class ProductDetailsComplex(productId: String, description: Map[String, String]) extends Product

case class PolymorphicInventory(products: List[Product])
```

Note that I removed the `Product` vs `ProductDetails` distinction, so an `Inventory` now just as a list of `Product`. I left the names `ProductDetailsSimple` and `ProductDetailsComplex` though I think they should be renamed.

Example usage:

```
val inv = PolymorphicInventory(
  List(
    ProductDetailsSimple(productId="Some_id", description="some description"),
    ProductDetailsComplex(productId="Some_id", description=Map("someKey" -> "somevalue"))
  )
)

val s = jsonMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(inv)
println("Polymorphic Inventory as JSON: "+s)
```

Output:

```
Polymorphic Inventory as JSON: {
  "products" : [ {
    "type" : "simple",
    "productId" : "Some_id",
    "description" : "some description"
  }, {
    "type" : "complex",
    "productId" : "Some_id",
    "description" : {
      "someKey" : "somevalue"
    }
  } ]
}
```

## 3. Remove the polymorphism

I suggest that polymorphism in this case isn't needed at all, and that the error is in trying to make "description" either a single string or a key/value map when they are really fields with distinct intentions.

Perhaps there is a data legacy issue involved (in which case see the custom deser suggestion), but if the data is in your control, I vote for "go simpler":

```
case class Product(productId: String,
                   description: String="",
                   attributes: Map[String, String]=Map.empty)

case class PlainInventory(products: List[Product])
```

I's more "scala-rific" to use `Option` to indicate the absence of a value, so:

```
case class Product(productId: String,
                   description: Option[String]=None,
                   attributes: Option[Map[String, String]]=None)
```

Example usage:

```
val inv = PlainInventory(
  List(
    Product(productId="Some_id", description=Some("some description")),
    Product(productId="Some_id", attributes=Some(Map("someKey" -> "somevalue")))
  )
)

val s = jsonMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(inv)
println("Plain Inventory as JSON: "+s)
```

Output:

```
Plain Inventory as JSON: {
  "products" : [ {
    "productId" : "Some_id",
    "description" : "some description"
  }, {
    "productId" : "Some_id",
    "attributes" : {
      "someKey" : "somevalue"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Working minimal code on [github](https://github.com/aellerton/so-scala-jackson-polymorphic).

Comment: Your 2nd solution modifies the existing JSON. How do you deal with it when you cannot change the JSON formatting ?

Comment: By "formatting" I think you mean "structure"? I commented about keeping the exact structure in solutions 1 and 3, basically saying to use solution 1. It's possible solution 2 could be made to work but if exact conformance to some non-Jackson-friendly JSON is needed, a custom deserialiser is the main option I can think of.

Comment: Agreed. But you mentioned that it's not the best solution, but I think that's the best one though! :)

Comment: "Best solution" is highly subjective and greatly dependent on variables local to your own scenario. If you are constrained to use a specific JSON structure that changes the available solutions :)

Comment: Fair enough. But the intermediate conversion seemed redundant to me. It may also turnout to be expensive! So I was wondering why you had mentioned that 1 is not the best solution

Comment: I don't think there is any intermediate conversion. Perhaps we are using different assumptions? Can you point out to me where the conversion is and I'll address.