# Scala sealed trait to JSON serialization

Tags: scala, jackson

I have next scala types:

```
case class Wrapper(v: Type)
sealed trait Type
case object TypeA extends Type
case object Typeb extends Type
```

I want to serialize and deserialize `Wrapper` using `jackson` with the following code:

```
val mapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

val src = Wrapper(TypeA)
val txt = mapper.writeValueAsString(src)
val dst: Wrapper = mapper.readValue(txt, classOf[Wrapper])
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work because `txt` is `"{"v":{}}"`.

How to serialize/deserialize it properly?

If `jackson` can't do this is there other library?

Comment: The thing is that you will have to include the `implementation` detail in your `json` representation. Such as `{ "__class": "com.example.TypeA"}` for class instances and `{ "__object": "com.example.TypeA"}` then take care of these in your custom deserialiser with PlayJson or SprayJson. Jackson can not handle `object` mixed in your Json, it will be able to handle any type of class based inheritance with `mapper.enableDefaultTyping()`

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027233/jackson-scala-json-deserialization-to-case-classes

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I understand that. Question is: how to do that?

Comment: @JakubZalas I tried to add `@JsonSubTypes` tag, but it doesn't word with `case object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that only possible way to do this is custom seralizer and deseralizer.

You have to implement `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` for sealed trait and mark you trait with `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize`.

Or you can register serealizer and deserializer in `ObjectMapper`.